# Proof for copula determined by correlation matrix

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, copula

How can I proof that the copula of an elliptical distribution $El(\mu, \sigma^2, g_n)$ is fully determined by the generator function $g_n$ and the correlation matrix extracted from $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Best of my knowledge, the elliptical copula does not determine by the generator function. A good book to read about Elliptical copula and how to generate it is: An introduction to copula by Nelsen 2006.

Comment: what about: $X\backsim El(\mu,\sigma^{2},g_{n})$ -> $X-\mu\backsim El(0,\sigma^{2},g_{n})$ This is a monotonic tranformation, therefore $X-\mu$ has the same copula therefore it doesn't depend on $\mu$?

Comment: Could you please add the book or source for your question? Or could you please expand your question?

Comment: I was wondering if you came to conclusion and for this and if so, how? Thanks!